# Add an exception to a proxy exception

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, proxy

Our company has a group policy that forces all (Win7) computers to use a proxy server with several exceptions.  One of the exceptions is the wildcard - `*.ourcompanydomain.com`.

However, we need to include just 1 subdomain of that wildcard - `proxyme.ourcompanydomain.com` - to go through the proxy instead of being excluded.

We know we could exclude all the subdomains of `ourcompanydomain.com` individually rather than using the wildcard, but there are dozens and the list changes regularly. This would be difficult to setup, let alone maintain.

Is there another way we could still exclude the wildcard `*.ourcompanydomain.com` and just re-include `proxyme.ourcompanydomain.com`?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using an Automatic Configuration Script a.k.a. PAC file.

From  the 'Automatically Detect Settings' section of [Understanding Web Proxy Configuration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/10/11/understanding-web-proxy-configuration/):

> The user may also directly specify the URL of a proxy configuration script using the second checkbox in the dialog. The URL field below points directly at the target script (e.g. http://proxy.contoso.com/proxy.pac).
>
> Proxy configuration scripts, whether discovered via WPAD, or manually specified by the user, are JavaScript files that expose at least one function FindProxyForURL(url, host). This function is called by the browser each time that it needs to decide where to send a given request. It returns a string which is either:
>
> “DIRECT” indicating that the request should bypass the proxy
>
> “PROXY PrimaryProxy:8080; BackupProxy:81” indicating that the request should be forwarded to the proxy PrimaryProxy on port 8080, unless that server is unreachable in which case the request should be sent to BackupProxy on port 81.

And based on the example in [the Wikipedia article about PAC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) I believe this should work for you:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) { 
    if (shExpMatch(host, "proxyme.mycompanydomain.com"))
    {
        return "PROXY myproxy.mycompanydomain.com:8080";
    }

    if (shExpMatch(host, "*.mycompanydomain.com"))
    {
        return "DIRECT";
    }
  
    return "PROXY myproxy.mycompanydomain.com:8080";
}
```